# Sharing cookie authentication from ASP.NET 5+ application to legacy ASP.NET 4.x

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, cookies

I searched and found some examples mentioning the sharing of authentication cookies between  .NET Framework and .NET Core/5+ applications, but most of citations are of cookies being generated in the older version of .NET being reused in Core, not the opposite that is what I need.

[Share Cookie authentication between ASP.NET Core 2.2 and ASP. NET MVC 5 (.NET Framework 4.6.1) without Microsoft.Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647573/share-cookie-authentication-between-asp-net-core-2-2-and-asp-net-mvc-5-net-fr)

[share authentication cookie between .NET Framework and .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60031362/share-authentication-cookie-between-net-framework-and-net-core)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#share-authentication-cookies-between-aspnet-4x-and-aspnet-core-apps

The closest case was this one.

[I need my .NET Framework 4.7.2 website to be able to use the authentication of my .NET Core Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70058135/i-need-my-net-framework-4-7-2-website-to-be-able-to-use-the-authentication-of-m)

But the version of reference is seems .NET Core 2.1 and some methods in the answer has been deprecated and I couldn't reproduce it. Also seems the authentication being performed in older application.

How could I setup a web app in ASP.NET 7 with individual accounts authentication and reuse this cookie to authorize other applications (legacy 4.x web apps modules, and also newer applications that'll be implemented)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The middleware `UseCookieAuthentication` is obsolete. Configure Cookie authentication with `AddAuthentication().AddCookie` When you regist the service ,and call `app.UseAuthentication()` middleware,Here's the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.cookieappbuilderextensions.usecookieauthentication?view=aspnetcore-2.2#microsoft-aspnetcore-builder-cookieappbuilderextensions-usecookieauthentication(microsoft-aspnetcore-builder-iapplicationbuilder)) related

You could try as below  in your .net core project and follow the case you provided

```
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(x =>
        {
            
            x.DataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(.......);
        }
        );

.....
app.UseAuthentication()
......
```